# Getting row value of last cell containing data in a Ms Excel file using PhpExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm using PhpExcel to process a Ms Excel file received from a customer. I want to get the row value of the last cell containing data in the file, so I use:

```
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
```

But $highestRow is larger than the correct value that I can see in the file. When I press "Ctrl + End", the focus moves to a 'blank' cell that has row value equal to $highestRow.

I don't understand how Ms Excel determines the 'last cell'. Anyway, I really need to get the last cell that contains data.

Answer (score 2):

The `getHighestRow()` method will return the highest row that contains anything in the sheet. That could include style information, images or other elements that aren't cell content.

Use the `getHighestDataRow()` method to get the highest row number for cells that have actual content. Note that a blank space or a null value in a cell can qualify as content.

Comment: Actually, I saw somewhere your similar answers related to getHighestDataRow(). I tried but it didn't work. I also deleted all blank cells then pressed "Ctrl + End" but the last cell was still a blank cell :(